# Algorithm to find maximum number of items that can be removed from buckets with set of condition

Tags: algorithms

I am looking for algorithm to rather complex problem and I am wondering if this is some well known problem or can be translated to one.

Let's say that i have buckets `B1, B2, B3` that contain some number of colored balls (red and green) and set of conditions `K1=(1 green, 2 red), K2=(2 green, 1 red), K3=(2 green, 1 red)` and `NK1=1, NK2=1, NK3=3`. This conditions says that `K1` is a set of `1 green` and `2 red` balls and that we need 1 such set `(NK1=1)` and that set need to be in one bucket (we cannot get balls for K1 from different buckets, but if NK1=2 for e.g then we can get one set from one bucket and another from another bucket) etc. Now for e.g. we have in bucket `B1` `1 green` and `2 red` balls, in `B2` `2 green` and `2 red` and in bucket `B3` `2 green` and `1 red`. The question is what is the maximum number of balls of each color that we can pull out of the each bucket so that given conditions are still met. In this example we cannot pull out any green balls and we can pull out one red ball from bucket `B2`. Then 1 `K1` is in `B1`, 1 `K2` is in `B2` or `B3` and 1 `K3` is in `B2` or `B3` but in other bucket than `K2`.

In reality I need to solve this problem for arbitrary number of buckets with balls in arbitrary number of colors and arbitrary numbers of conditions (conditions will contain small number of colors but there will be large number of different colors in total) and in SQL (but SQL part is not that important for now).

Comment: Can balls be used more than once? For example, if I have a bucket with two red balls and two green, can I satisfy one (1 green, 2 red) and one (2 green, 1 red) with that bucket alone?

Comment: No, you can use balls only one time.